# R code (RStudio) does not work on my laptop, while working on another laptop

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm applying predictive modelling (gradient boosting machine), and my code has an error on my laptop, but not in the university computer.

I think that the error is in the line 203, **train**.

Error:

```
Error in train.default(training_data[, predictorsNames], training_data[,  : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
2: In train.default(training_data[, predictorsNames], training_data[,  :
  missing values found in aggregated results

    # TRAINING & CROSSVALIDATION SETS

    filtered_processed_dataset$IsDelayed<-ifelse(filtered_processed_dataset$IsDelayed==1,'yes','nope')
    filtered_processed_dataset$IsDelayed<-as.factor(filtered_processed_dataset$IsDelayed)
    outcomeName<-'IsDelayed'
    predictorsNames<-names(filtered_processed_dataset)[names(filtered_processed_dataset)!=outcomeName]

    inTrain<-caret::createDataPartition(filtered_processed_dataset$IsDelayed,p=.85,list=FALSE)
    training_data<-filtered_processed_dataset[inTrain,]
    crossvalidation_data<-filtered_processed_dataset[-inTrain,]

    # GRADIENT BOOSTING MACHINE 

    getModelInfo()$gbm$type

    rownames(training_data)<-NULL
    gbmGrid<-expand.grid(interaction.depth=c(1,5,9), n.trees=100, shrinkage=0.1)

    fitControl<-trainControl(
      method='cv',
      number=3,
      returnResamp='none',
      verbose=FALSE,
      summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
      classProbs=TRUE)

   **g<-train(training_data[,predictorsNames], training_data[,outcomeName],
     method='gbm',
     trControl=fitControl,
     metric="ROC",
     tuneGrid=gbmGrid)**

   crossvalidation_data<-as.data.frame(crossvalidation_data)
   rownames(crossvalidation_data)<-NULL

   p_gbm<-predict(g, crossvalidation_data[,predictorsNames], type='prob')

   auc<-pROC::roc(ifelse(crossvalidation_data[,outcomeName]=="yes",1,0),p_gbm[[2]])

   print(auc)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is absolutely not reproducible, I think there aren't many people that can help you.
Why did you tag the question with [tag:rstudio]? Have you tried running the code outside Rstudio to confirm this is an R issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sessionInfo()` on both computers in order to obtain information on the loaded packages and your `R` configuration. As you expect your code to be [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) there are two possible outcomes:

1. Your configurations differ, one version or **R** is older/newer or uses different libraries. This impacts how the code is executed.
2. Your data sets differ. You can exclude that easily, have a look at the package `compare` for example.

   - It may be worth exploring that the previous work, which you might have done, did not leave any other objects in your **R** environments, check this using `ls` and clean using `rm(list = ls())` *(careful, the command will remove all objects)*.

---

As a side point, you may consider having a look at the [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/). Packrat would enable you to maintain consistency with respect to the packages you are using across different environments.